# Why does File->Print and window.print() give me different output?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, printing

We're having trouble with Chrome (v74) not using our print styles when we do `window.print();` with JavaScript, but they are being used when we do `File->Print` or right-click then `Print` from the context menu. Also, inline styles on some of the elements, like `border: 3px dashed #000`, aren't being printed when we use `window.print()`.

The print styles are in the `<head>` without a `rel`, so we're not worrying about loading in an external resource:

```
<style>
  @media print {
    .myClass {
      ...
    }
  }
</style>
```

Also tried:

```
<style media="print">
  .myClass {
    ...
  }
</style>
```

Is there a reason why the JavaScript method is doing something different than the File->Print approach?

UPDATE: also wanted to mention that this is a react application. Not sure if this makes a difference. Again, File->Print works fine, but JavaScript window.print() doesn't.

UPDATE: I just discovered that `window.print()` when done from the debug console works perfectly. The `window.print()` call from my code is being done from the react code. Does react do something different with `window.print()`?

Comment: Different how??

Comment: Can you share screenshots of how they're different?

Comment: Different in that File->Print uses our print stylesheet while window.print() doesn't.

Comment: How is your styling being compiled/applied?